# GWTP bind enum in GIN

Tags: java, gwt, compiler-errors, gwt-platform, gwt-gin

I'm trying to put a enumeration into the ginjector with these lines of code:

ClientGinjector.java

```
MyEnum getMyEnum();
```

ClientModule.java

```
bind(MyEnum.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

But when I'm trying to compile I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Error injecting bla.blup.MyEnum: Unable to create or inherit
>   binding: Binding requested for constant key 'bla.blup.MyEnum' but no
>   explicit binding was found

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An enum class cannot be constructed, its only valid instances are its enum values. That menas you have to bind a specific enum value that will be injected into whatever field or parameter of that enum type.

Guice/GIN encourages you to use binding annotations for constants, so you can possibly inject different constant values depending on context; e.g.

```java
@Named("foo") @Inject MyEnum myEnum;

–

bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("foo")).to(MyEnum.FOO);
```

If you don't want to use a binding annotation (because you know you'll only ever want a single enum value throughout your app), you cannot use `bindConstant()`, but you can use `toInstance`:

```java
@Inject MyEnum myEnum;

…

bind(MyEnum.class).toInstance(MyEnum.FOO);
```

This will only work in Guice though, not in GIN, which [doesn't have `toInstance`](https://code.google.com/p/google-gin/wiki/GinFaq#What_bindings_don%27t_work?). In GIN, you have to use a `Provider` class or a `@Provides` method:

```java
class MyEnumProvider implements Provider<MyEnum> {
  @Override
  public MyEnum get() {
    return MyEnum.FOO;
  }
}
…
bind(MyEnum.class).toProvider(MyEnumProvider.class);
```

or

```java
@Provides
MyEnum provideMyEnum() {
  return MyEnum.FOO;
}
```

Both approaches above will also work with Guice.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. My usecase would match your second alternative without annotation. But i have no method "toInstance" on "bind(...)". Maybe this is because my "ClientModule" is an extension of "AbstractPresenterModule" (GWTP).

Comment: Aw snap! My bad, `toInstance` is not in GIN, only in Guice. In GIN you have to use a `Provider` or a `@Provides` method. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

> A constant (primitive type, String, Class or an enum) must be explicitly bound (using bindConstant() or bind()) in your GinModule (because there's no sensible default value that GIN would inject).
>
> [That's what GIN is telling you.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-gin/7j-2sQje9pM)

The file is where the binding is requested (i.e. where the dependency is declared) that GIN cannot honor.

Comment: Thanks, but I already read this google group entry. I just don't get what i did wrong. Because i bind this enum. See my starting post.

Comment: what about the location of that Enum ?

Comment: The Enum lies in a second projects package. But this package is inherited in the Project.gwt.xml. I use other classes from that package without any problems.